# How to use initialize in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

In the `initialze` action we pass an object which tell the forma name and the initial values. But how does it understand which value will be for which `Field`.

Like if I have 5 Fields in the redux form and want to initialze only 2 Fields. Then how will the `initialze` action will understand for which Field the initial values are provided.

https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/props.md/#-code-initialize-data-object-function-code-

Comment: Please also keep in mind, if you are just learning Redux, that it is generally not recommended (for years) to keep forms in Redux and even redux-form has a message in the front page of their documentation suggesting to use another library that works without Redux.
If you are following a Redux tutorial now that shows you redux-form, it is horribly outdated. For up-to-date Redux tutorials, see the official docs at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the `initialze` action we pass an object which tell the forma name
> and the initial values. How does it understand which value will be
> for which `Field`.

The object with initial values will (it should) have keys that match the field input `name` attributes.

Example:

```
<Field
  autoComplete="email"
  component={RenderTextField}
  id="login-email"
  label={formatMessage(strings.loginUsername)}
  name="email"
  type="text"
/>
```

If the form is initialized with `initialize('login', { email: state.emailAddress });` it will match/assign the `state.emailAddress` to the value of the input with matching `name` attribute, `email` in this case.